Interface with PCB for Hardware/Software Hacking
I have the main pcb from a Philips Dreamstation, but don't have the power delivery board. I know it was connected to a 10 pin connector on the board, and when I tried to use the onboard micro-usb port, the board did not receive power. There are test points on the board that I might be able to power it from, but there's also this jtag-ish looking connector. Here's the fcc page on the product, where you might be able to get some better pictures. How can I power this device and what interface should I use to access the software? Thanks!



